# Comment retranscrire une troncation orale ?

Tags: usage, oral, registre-familier

Quand j’écris un message électronique, j’ai tendance à privilégier un style plutôt familier qui s’apparente à une retranscription d’oral.

Il arrive par conséquent que je doive retranscrire un mot tronqué. À l’oral je parle plus volontiers d’une « répèt’ » que d’une *répétition* ; à chaque fois que je veux l’écrire, je me demande comment.

Vous pouvez constater que je privilégie l’apostrophe, pour préserver le mot original, mais que je modifie tout de même l’accent, ce qui n’est guère cohérent. Le point me semblerait au bas mot étrange. J’ai déjà lu « une répète », mais ça ne me plaît guère car j’y vois un mot nouveau que je n’entends pas.

Savez-vous si certains usages sont plus fréquents ou plus recommandés que d’autres et pourquoi ?

Comment: J'ai failli suggérer le remplacement de l'étrange *troncation* par une plus classique *troncature*. Et puis j'ai quand même vérifié vite fait. Et j'ai bien fait, *troncation* est juste!

Answer (score 3):

Personnellement, je choisis l'une ou l'autre des écritures en fonction du destinataire du message et non en fonction du moyen de diffusion de ce dernier.

Pour un message à destination amicale, j'aurais tendance à utiliser le mot *répèt'* alors que si le message est à destination professionnelle, j'écrirais volontairement *répétition*. A noter que ce dernier choix me permet de ne pas trop m'habituer à utiliser les troncations car plus on les écrit, plus on a tendance ensuite à les exprimer à l'oral (ce qui peut être mal perçu dans certains contextes : professionnel par exemple).

Sinon, je suis entièrement d'accord sur ta réfléxion sur le mot *répète*.